# Using TauDEM in QGIS 2.18.15 - error "mpiexex is not recognized..."

Tags: qgis, taudem

I am attempting to use TauDEM tools to model an existing watershed. I have installed the "TauDEM 5.3 Complete Windows Installer" mentioned on the download page (http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/downloads.html). But when I attempt to run the "Pit Remove" command I get the message described in this thread:

https://tutel.me/c/gis/questions/164935/running+taudem+in+qgis

I've attempted to uninstall and check my file paths as the person who has answered the question suggested, but this hasn't fixed the problem. Has anyone else had any luck overcoming this problem?

Comment: check this post  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164935/running-taudem-in-qgis